# CSS position fixed moved childrens

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create chat just like facebook or google. I have created chat-container class which holds users list and chat boxes.

`chat-container` is fixed with `bottom:0` and `right: 0`, so its position is perfect.

```
.chat-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

The problem is that I am getting a lot of users from server. So, I would like to add `max-height:` value. When I add this property then all my chat-boxes include userslist is being misaligned.

Each chat box has class chat-box and and inside chat-body..chat-box

```
.chat-box {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.chat-body {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

How can I solve that?

EDIT - HTML:

```
<div class="chat-container">
          <div class="chat-box" *ngFor="let chat of openedChats; let first = first;">
            <p-panel [toggleable]="true">
              <p-header>
                <a class="ui-panel-titlebar-icon ui-panel-titlebar-toggler ui-corner-all ui-state-default" (click)="onCloseChat(chat)">
                  <span class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></span>
                </a>
                <b>{{chat.recipient.name}}</b>
              </p-header>
              <div class="chat-body" #chatbody>
                <div *ngFor="let message of chat.messages">
                  <!--TODO: Get current user id | change to ngClass-->
                  <div *ngIf="message.sender.id != loggedUserId" class="chat-inner-message">
                    {{message.message}}
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="message.sender.id == loggedUserId" class="chat-my-message">
                    {{message.message}}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <input type="text" class="chat-input" (keyup.enter)="onSendMessage(messageInput, chat.recipient.id)" #messageInput>
              <button pButton type="button" label="Send" (click)="onSendMessage(messageInput, chat.recipient.id)" style="width:100%"></button>
              <!--<span *ngIf='first'>{{setChatInputFocus()}}</span>-->
            </p-panel>
          </div>
          <div class="chat-box">
            <p-panel [toggleable]="true" [collapsed]="true">
              <p-header>
                Chat
              </p-header>
              <ul class="ultima-menu">
                <li *ngFor="let user of visibleUsers" (click)="onUserSelected($event, user.id)" style="padding: 3%">
                  <div style="display: inline; cursor: pointer;">
                    <div>
                      <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="{{user?.settings?.photoSrc}}" class="circular-portrait" width="30px" height="30px"
                        alt="{{user.name}}">
                        <span>
                      {{user.name}} {{user.surname}}
                    </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <hr>
              <input pInputText placeholder="Search" [ngModel]="userTypeaheadText" (ngModelChange)="userTypeahedChanged($event)">
            </p-panel>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of the HTML structure?

Comment: Sure give me a sec

Comment: Try adding `overflow: scroll;` to the `.chat-container` CSS. Does that solve your problem?